# What does a circumflex in a require property mean?

Tags: angularjs

I am looking at some [AngularJS-based code](https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard/blob/master/src/step.js). It contains the following line:

```
require: '^wizard',
```

**In this line, what does the circumflex character (`^`) mean?**

This sounds like a question that should be easily answered by a glance into the documentation. Unfortunately, using the search feature on [AngularJS.org](https://angularjs.org/) to look for *circumflex* does not yield a single hit. Looking directly for *^* returns many results, but at least the first few of them that I checked do not even appear to contain that symbol - hence, I guess the circumflex character is simply ignored in the search. Likewise, when searching directly in Google for *angularjs circumflex*, I am finding [questions on Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062882/why-can-the-circumflex-sign-be-used-for-control-chars-in-delphi-and-is-it-a-good), [encoding problems related to circumflex characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123529/angularjs-unexpected-token-when-parsing-large-json-payload), [resources on accented characters](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/accentedcharacters.htm), etc.

Comment: You should search for 'require' instead of 'circumflex' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (A ^ prefix would make the directive look for the controller on its own element or its parents; without any prefix, the directive would look on its own element only.)

In here, The directive has a require option with value `^wizard`. When a directive uses this option, $compile will throw an error unless the specified controller is found.

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive